# DecorationViews on UICollectionView are duplicated on every insert

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a book shelf with an UICollectionView, not unlike the iBooks app.

It works nicely, however whenever I *insert* a new item into the view (by calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`), the item is inserted correctly, but my shelf items (which are DecorationViews, subclasses of `UICollectionReusableView`) are getting darker and darker, obviously being painted over and over again.
However, if a call `reloadData` on the `UICollectionView` everything is painted correct.

This is what I did in my derived `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class:

- `- (void)prepareLayout`    Calculating the frames for the
  DecorationViews
- `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:   Adding
  UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for all shelves which intersect the
  rect
- `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
  *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`   Adjusting `zIndex` for my item attributes to 1
- `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
  *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString *) atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`   Adjusting `zIndex` for my shelf
  attributes to 0

That's it.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like (another) bug with decoration views. I've filed a [bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2662407) that they're duplicated when the device is rotated.

Comment: Hi Ash
I am having the same issue don't suppose you got any feedback on the bug you filed ?

Comment: Not yet, I'm afraid. I'll update the openradar if that happens.